# How to downgrade from Android 10?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, crashes, downgrade

Android 10 is extremely unstable on my Pixel XL. Most apps crashed within a few seconds after open, even including Google Play Store. That means, I could not do any new app install, because Google Play Store crashes within 3 seconds; I could not do any app update, because it crashes within 3 seconds.

And the chat/phone call of Support function in Settings disappear. That means I have no more support.

I could not take screenshot, because it crashes.

Any idea how to downgrade from Android 10 without any data loss without any app reinstallation, just like the way we do the upgrade install (we do not need to do any backup)?

Comment: Your firmware might be downgrade protected because of security risks, and even if it doesn't, downgrading with dirty flashing (not deleting user data) would most likely cause boot issue or the crash issues you are having (because of the downgraded Android unable to make sense of existing data from a futuristic Android). For example, say if contacts database structure was updated in Android 10 than Android 9's contacts manager would not understand it and simply crash on the screen. Btw, you can't downgrade without an unlocked bootloader either.

Comment: Point is, you can only do a factory reset at this stage to fix your problems or dig deeper using [tag:logcat] to find the problems  but with the hope that you won't be able to fix the problem without reset either